# Race condition GCD

Tags: ios, xamarin, grand-central-dispatch

I want to keep alive main thread to not freeze my application. But i don't know how to make non race condition with my async task. So i need wait my async task, but without blocking mainQueue.

```
public override bool ShouldPerformSegue(string segueIdentifier, NSObject sender)
{
    bool isAlowed = false;
    ActivityIndicator.StartAnimating();
    DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.High).DispatchAsync(()=>
        {
        NSThread.SleepFor(2);
        isAlowed = true;
        });
    return isAlowed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than initiating the segue and then trying to determine if the segue should be performed, asynchronously, simply handle the user interaction without triggering the segue, determine if the segue should be performed and *then* initiate the segue.

I can't give you exact code since I don't know Xamarin well enough, but the pseudo-code is something like:

```
handleHandleButtonTap() {
   initiateBackgroundCheckWithHandler( isAllowed(bool) {
       if isAllowed {
          performSegueWithIdentifer("SomeSegue")  // You need to dispatch this on the main queue
       }
   })
}
```

Xamarin / C# example:

```
void SomeButton_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isAllowed = false;
    InvokeInBackground(() =>
    {
        // Do some task... and optionally assign isAllowed to true...
        if (isAllowed)
            DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => PerformSegue("SomeSegue", this));
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is what im needed... Thank you! I must read about all override methods, to avoid so stupid questions..

Comment: It wasn't a stupid question at all. It takes experience with a platform to understand how it works and to best to get the outcome you want.